# getExternalStorageDirectory on Android 10

Tags: android, permissions

In my app, I have to access the root of `sdcard` which I have been doing with `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` before API level 29. Now on devices running API level 29, I get Permission Denied. I am aware of methods like `getExternalFilesDir(null)` but this is useless to me because it leads to the directory `Android/data/your_package_name/files` and not to `storage/emulated/0/` which I would need. Is that doable somehow?

Comment: "Is that doable somehow?" -- no. You no longer have direct filesystem access to arbitrary locations on external storage, starting with Android 10. You can use the Storage Access Framework to let the user choose content from anywhere on external storage (or elsewhere), but you do not control where that content resides.

Comment: `because it leads to the directory Android/data/your_package_name/files`. No. That is no path.  It leads to `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/your_package_name/files`.